# getting value error while using datetime.strptime()

Tags: python, datetime, data-mining, strptime

i am using  `datetime.strptime()` in order to convert the timesatmp string received from the API to separate the date and time. one of the example :

```
from datetime import 
datetime.strptime("2019-11-14T03:41:12.869000Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%
```

and I can't figure out what is wrong with this `"2019-11-14T03:41:12.869000Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z"` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`%Z`](https://strftime.org/) is *Time zone name (empty string if the object is naive).* for example `UTC`. If trailing `Z` appears in all your strings use `Z` rather than `%Z`, that is

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-11-14T03:41:12.869000Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
print(dt)
```

output

```
2019-11-14 03:41:12.869000
```

Comment: If you ignore the Z by passing a literal Z, you end up with naive datetime. That can be pretty misleading if you expect UTC since Python treats naive datetime as local time.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the % before Z and it should work!

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("2019-11-14T03:41:12.869000Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```